# Assignment of a complex constructor through new

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a confusion. Following is a code snippet.

I want to create a dynamic array of five class objects using `new`and but i want to run a loop to assign the first parameter of constructor using the loop counter. Something like.

```
class A {
    public:
        A(int _x, int _y):x(_x),y(_y) {}
    private:
        int x,y;
};

int main() {
    A* a = new A[5];   //compiler error
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        a[i] = A(i, 10);
    }
}
```

Can some one please tell me whats the correct syntax to do this as I dont have a simple constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A* a = new A[5];
```

tries to construct `5` objects of type `A` by using the default constructor of `A` that is not present in your class. You should implement it:

```
class A {
    public:
        A() : x_(0), y_(10) { }                 // default constructor
        A(int x, int y) : x_(x), y_(y) { }
    private:
        int x_;
        int y_;
};
```

but note that it would be better idea to use `std::vector` instead of this dynamically allocated array:

```
std::vector<A> a(5);
```

which also constructs `5` objects of type `A` by using the default constructor :)

Answer (score 7):

This line

```
A* a = new A[5];
```

requires that `A` be default constructible. So an easy option would be to add a default constructor to `A`:

```
 A(): x(), y() {} // zero-initializes x and y
```

Note that in C++ one would usually favour using an `std::vector<A>` in this case. It takes case of all memory management, so it is not necessary to call `new` and `delete` explicitly. It can also be resized dynamically. This would construct an `std::vector<A>` with five default constructed `A` objects:

```
std::vector<A> a(5);
```

although you probably want to create an empty one and push values into it in a loop.

```
std::vector<A> a;
for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
    a.push_back(A(i, 10));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you do not have a constructor that takes no parameters you can either do:

```
A(int _x = 0, int _y = 0):x(_x),y(_y) {}
```

Or

```
A() : x(0), y(0) {}
```

And instead of the for loop write

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
    a[i].set(i, 10);
}
```

With a suitable method `set`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- either use `A** a = new A*[5]` and `a[i] = new A(i, 10)`, that is to
  say an array of pointers to `A` as opposed to an array of objects.
- Or include a default constructor `A(): x(0), y(0) {}` or just add default parameters to your existing constructor.

Your current compiler error is because `new A[5]` builds 5 contiguous `A`s and to do that it allocates `5 * sizeof(A)` bytes of memory and calls 5 times the default constructor of `A` (a constructor without any parameters), but this default constructor is not available in your class A.

Comment: There is no need for a user provided assignment operator.

Comment: Well indeed not necessary for this class. I removed it from my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you don't have a default constructor. When you call new, it needs to create objects somehow, and couldn't. You have to either provide one (i.e. one that initializes `x` and `y` with zeros) or use [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) if C++11 is an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a default constructor to be defined then try this,

```
int main() 
{    
    A* a[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
      a[i] = new A(i, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: and get O(n) memory allocations and lose locality. usually a bad idea for C++ code.

Comment: it's just like a vector based versus list based approach. Both has got pros and cons!

Comment: and what pros do you see in your suggestion?

Comment: What if A* a = new A[MAX]; // MAX is huge and memory allocation fails?   Though it is a O(n) memory allocation, we will atleast have some objects constructed even if heap allocation fails for some reasons.

Comment: 1. usually when memory allocation fails there is no sense to continue work. 2. for unusual cases there is no general solution, still it looks more promising to allocate memory in chunks or use array with smaller number of elements.

Comment: Depends! we may still have some objects constructed. If feasible employ them :)

Comment: Yep, it is more promising to allocate in smaller chunks.